# Can anyone tell me how to find fundamental system for non-constant matrices ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I know how to calculate it if the coefficient-matrix is constant, but what bout if it's non-constant ?

> Let $A(t)\in \Bbb R^{2x2} $ with $y'=A(x)y$ ,where
>
> $$A(x)=\begin{pmatrix} -x^2 & 1 \\ 2x-x^4-\frac{x}{ln(x)} & x^2+\frac{1}{x ln(x)}\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> calculate one fundamental-system

what do I have to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The system is
$$(1)\quad y_1'=-x^2y_1+y_2\\
(2)\quad y_2'=(2x-x^4-\frac{x}{\ln x})y_1+(x^2+\frac{1}{x\ln x})y_2.$$
Performing $(2)-x^2\cdot (1)$, we get
$$y_2'-x^2y_1'=(2x-\frac{x}{\ln x})y_1+\frac{1}{x\ln x}y_2.$$

Now setting $Y=\ln x\cdot y_2-x\ln x\cdot y_1$. Doing some algebra, you will get an ODE for $Y$:
$$Y'=\frac{2}{x\ln x}Y.$$

After solving this, you can plug the result into (1) to get $y_1$. Then $y_2$ can be solved accordingly.

Comment: So $Y=(y_1,y_2)$ and would $Y=\{y_1,y_2\}$ be the fundamental system ?

Comment: @pinkpanther5 Yes, I think so, especially since it says calculate "one" fundamental system.